# Selenium C# Open New Tab CTRL+T Not working with CHROME

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

```
static void Main()
{
    IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://google.com");
    IWebElement body = driver.FindElement(By.TagName("body"));

    body.SendKeys(Keys.Control + "t");

}
```

This is the code that I am trying to use to open a new tab and its not working, I am not getting any errors nothing, the driver opens Google and thats all....
I have searched a lot and found many tutorials even videos where people are using the exact same code and it works for them, but for me it doesnt and I can't figure it out...

I tried sending Keys.Shift + "t" to the search field and it works, it writes a capital T in the field

I have also tried

```
Actions act = new Actions(driver);
act.KeyDown(Keys.Control).SendKeys("t").Perform();
```

And it still does not work, but again if I change Keys.Control to Keys.Shift it writes, seems like nothing that involves Keys.Control is working!!

Edit: I have tried running the code with a IE Driver and it worked there, it opens new tab, but it does not open new tabs on Chrome?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Thanks for the answers! I did it with JavaScript.

```
((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript("window.open();");
```

Answer (score 6):

Looks like it's a "feature" of the chrome driver.

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=581

> This is a limitation in the way we simulate keyboard input in ChromeDriver. Keys get sent directly to the render process, bypassing the browser process. So any keyboard shortcut handlers in the browser process will not be invoked by sendKeys().

Comment: Google, don't be evil ¬¬ Thanks for the info ! Upvoted.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("body")).SendKeys(Keys.Control + "t");
driver.SwitchTo().Window(driver.WindowHandles.Last());
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.google.com")
```

Comment: Thats the other strange thing, I don't have driver.WindowHandles.Last()

Comment: Add "using System.Linq;" for access to Linq methods.

Comment: Tried, still not working, just nothing happens, no matter what combination I try with Keys.Control its not working, but Keys.Shift is working...

Comment: I have just tried running my code on Internet Explorer driver and it works, but it does not work with Chrome..??

Comment: Does not work with SeleniumDriver v3.141.0 and ChromeDriver  2.45.615291. A new tab does not open.

Answer (score 0):

If your on a mac, use Keys.Command instead of Keys.Control:

```
body.SendKeys(Keys.Command + "t");
```

Comment: Thanks, but I am not on Mac

Comment: No problem just a thought - your code looks reasonable.