# Java selenium: open new tab

Tags: java, selenium

So i have this `URL` that i want to surf into in new tab, the link is not clickable so when i click on this nothing happen and this will not work (even not manually):

```
    WebElement hrefLink;
        actions.keyDown(Keys.SHIFT).click(hrefLink).keyUp(Keys.SHIFT).build().perform();

        // Handle windows change.
ArrayList<String> tabs = new ArrayList<String>(Browser.driver().getWindowHandles());

     // Switch to the new tab.
     driver.switchTo().window(tabs.get(1));
```

So i try this approach:

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("body")).sendKeys(Keys.CONTROL + "t");
```

And no new tab openning.

Any suggestions ?

**UPDATE**

This is my web URL: `https://bitly.com/`

Comment: Danny will it be possible for you to give us an example of such web element from some public website. That way we can help you out with the exact solution as well. It's hard to determine your problem area by just looking into the code.

Comment: Pleas see my update, insert some web url and it will return short link that you can only copy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can start with this workaround:

```
void openNewTab(WebDriver driver) {
    ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("window.open('https://google.com');"); 
}
```

And [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43645129/selenium-c-sharp-open-new-tab-ctrlt-not-working-with-chrome) is the question that resembles to yours. Maybe it will be useful ;)