# Is there a way to zoom out in chrome using c# and selenium other than CSS zoom?

Tags: css, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I access a web page (angular) using selenium. If I zoom out the page manually in chrome then the menu appears and it is easier to navigate. I want to do the same with selenium and c#. A lot of post ask similar question but not exactly the same. Let me explain:

1. css zoom

   ```
   ((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript("document.body.style.zoom = '70%'");
   ```

   The page is zoomed out but the angular webpage does not detect it, the hidden menu is not displayed, so it is not good for me.
2. zoom with keys:

   ```
   new Actions(driver).SendKeys(Keys.Control).SendKeys(Keys.Subtract).Perform();
   ```

   It does not change the zoom level for me. There is no exception, it just does nothing. I tried other SendKeys method without success.
3. zoom with chrome settings

   ```
   driver.Url = "chrome://settings";
   ((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript("chrome.settingsPrivate.setDefaultZoom(0.66);");
   ```

   This changes the zoom level but after the first line there will an error message: "Failed to load pepper module from internal-not-yet-present".
   After that the webdriver works improperly. For example, the code which clicked a button which worked before does not work anymore.

Any new idea?

Comment: What does trigger the menu toggle?

Comment: Answer to: @KoshVery. If the web page is not zoomed out, then an icon must be pressed to bring out the menu. I can do it, but it would be easier to zoom out. In that case the webpage "realign" itself, and the menu will be visible. If I use css-zoom then the wepage is zoomed out but without displaying the menu.

Answer (score 0):

To zoom out as an alternative you can use the following solution:

```
((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript("document.body.style.transform='scale(0.6)';");
```

**Note**: Zoom In/Out during *Test Execution* through *Selenium* to any value other than 100% may induce instability in your *Tests*. Specifically, [Required Configuration](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/InternetExplorerDriver#required-configuration) section of [Internet Explorer Driver](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/InternetExplorerDriver#internet-explorer-driver) clearly mentions:

> The browser zoom level must be set to **100%** so that the native mouse events can be set to the correct coordinates.

Comment: OP is talking specifically about chromedriver... why are you talking about configs for IE?

Comment: This solution is just an other version of "css zoom".  It zooms out but the angular webpage does not detect it, the hidden menu is not displayed.

Comment: modifying `document.body.style.zoom` messes up the page layout of complex pages; it's not a general solution

Answer (score 0):

I found that "2. zoom with keys" does not work because of chromedriver shortcomming. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/43665060/5852947

What is more, even if you zoom out manually chromedriver has another issue. See https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=628

driver.FindElement(...) will not work properly while zoomed out.