# How to open 2 different links in two tabs using a singe Selenium c# Webdriver/ChromeDriver?

Tags: c#, selenium

Following is my code

```
 IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
 driver.Url = "https://www.google.com/";

 driver.Url = "https://login.yahoo.com/";
```

I want that both the links should be opened in different tabs of same browser window

How to achieve this?

TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:
`((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript("window.open();");`
instead of

```
IWebElement body = driver.FindElement(By.TagName("body"));

body.SendKeys(Keys.Control + "t");
```

If you need to continue working on the first window you need to follow steps described [here](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/26800/how-to-switch-from-one-tab-to-another-tab-in-chrome) just remember to change `Ctrl + t` with the JavaScript above.

Comment: It's working .thanks. After execution the focus is on the second tab. Is there a way to keep the focus on first tab?

Comment: Are you asking about the focus of Chrome browser itself, not the WebDriver?

Comment: Yes , the Chrome browser. I want the url in first tab to be the main tab i.e the tab in focus

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do that as follows:

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("body")).sendKeys(Keys.CONTROL+"t");
driver.get("https://login.yahoo.com/");
```

Good luck

Andreas

Comment: What is "t". does it represent tab key? I tried the above in c# , It does not work.The second link opens in the first tab itself.

Comment: It's a known issue. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43645129/selenium-c-sharp-open-new-tab-ctrlt-not-working-with-chrome. See my answer for better solution